# Visual Studio 2015 keeps offering me an obsolete update for Tools for Universal Windows Apps 1.1.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, updates, obsolete

This isn't fatal, of course. Just annoying. I'm wondering if anyone's seen this and found a way to solve it.

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 installed, with Tools for Universal Windows Apps 1.3.2 installed.

In Extensions and Updates, under Updates -> Product Updates, I'm being offered Tools for Universal Windows Apps 1.1.1. It claims that I have 14.0.23121 installed, and it wants me to install 14.0.23309.

Pressing the Update button takes me to VS setup, where it informs me (correctly) that I already have 1.3.2 installed.

Uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2015 doesn't help, unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: report it on connect: connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Comment: Yeah, not a bad idea.

Comment: ok, I see you reported it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2751943